# How to delete existing file with Alamofire 5?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I had a working code with AlamoFire 4 that was deleting files if they were already in the temporary and destination folder :

```
if response.destinationURL != nil  {
    elf.deleteFileIfexist(dossierToDelete: response.destinationURL)
}
if response.temporaryURL != nil  {
    self.deleteFileIfexist(dossierToDelete: response.temporaryURL)
}
```

Everything was fine, but with AlmoFire 5 everything is broken (it's exhausting and time consuming that every new version breaks things)

Here is the destination:

> let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)

The download

> AF.download(urlString, method: .get, parameters: parameters, to: destination)

Since the file already exists, Alamofire throws this error

> Alamofire.AFError.downloadedFileMoveFailed

So how can I delete this file?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `suggestedDownloadDestination(for:in:options:)` function, you can pass `.removePreviousFile` as `options` parameter:

```
let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(
    for: .documentDirectory,
    options: .removePreviousFile
)
```

From `DownloadRequest.Options.removePreviousFile` documentation:

> Specifies that any previous file at the destination URL should be
> removed.